# Shouldn't this mutex "lock" if you are trying to access a global variable?

Tags: c, multithreading, system, mutex, condition-variable

My source code below works exactly as its supposed to. The problem is that I managed to get it working only because I used print f statements to find out where the code was getting "stuck". I don't understand why in the inner while loops the mutex must be unlocked instead of locked by the function using it. I'm sorry if that isn't very clear, but I'm having problems understanding it myself.

For sanity sake I'll put the snip of code in question at the top on its own, and the full source code below it.

```
            // if buffer is full, release mutex lock and check again
        if (shared_count == NITEMS)
        {
            // Signal consumer thread and sleep
            pthread_cond_signal(&bufferNotEmpty);
            pthread_cond_wait(&bufferNotFull,&mutex);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            break;
        }
```

Here is the full source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NITEMS 10               // number of items in shared buffer

// shared variables
char shared_buffer[NITEMS];     // echo buffer
int shared_count;               // item count

pthread_mutex_t mutex;          // pthread mutex
pthread_cond_t bufferNotEmpty;  // pthread condition variable for consumer thread
pthread_cond_t bufferNotFull;   // pthread condition variable for producer thread

unsigned int prod_index = 0;    // producer index into shared buffer
unsigned int cons_index = 0;    // consumer index into shared buffer

// function prototypes
void * producer(void *arg);
void * consumer(void *arg);

int main() 
{ 
    pthread_t prod_tid, cons_tid1, cons_tid2; 

    // initialize pthread variables
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&bufferNotEmpty, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&bufferNotFull, NULL);

    // start producer thread
    pthread_create(&prod_tid, NULL, producer, NULL);

    // start consumer threads
    pthread_create(&cons_tid1, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&cons_tid2, NULL, consumer, NULL);

    // wait for threads to finish
    pthread_join(prod_tid, NULL);
    pthread_join(cons_tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(cons_tid2, NULL);

    // clean up
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&bufferNotEmpty);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&bufferNotFull);

    return 0;
}

// producer thread executes this function
void * producer(void *arg)
{
    char key;

    while (1)
    {
        // read input key
        scanf("%c", &key);

        while (1)
        {
            // acquire mutex lock
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

            // if buffer is full, release mutex lock and check again
            if (shared_count == NITEMS)
            {
                // Signal consumer thread and sleep
                pthread_cond_signal(&bufferNotEmpty);
                pthread_cond_wait(&bufferNotFull,&mutex);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                break;
            }

            else
                break;
        }

        // store key in shared buffer
        shared_buffer[prod_index] = key;

        // update shared count variable
        shared_count++;


        // update producer index
        if (prod_index == NITEMS - 1)
            prod_index = 0;
        else
            prod_index++;

        // release mutex lock and signal consumer thread
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
        pthread_cond_signal(&bufferNotEmpty);
    }

    return NULL;
}

// consumer thread executes this function
void * consumer(void *arg)
{
    char key;

    int id = (int)pthread_self();

    while (1)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            // acquire mutex lock
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

            // if buffer is empty, wake producer thread and sleep
            if (shared_count == 0)
            {
                pthread_cond_signal(&bufferNotFull);
                pthread_cond_wait(&bufferNotEmpty,&mutex);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            } 

            else
                break;
        }

        // read key from shared buffer
        key = shared_buffer[cons_index];

        // echo key
        printf("consumer %d %c\n", id, key);

        // update shared count variable
        shared_count--;

        // update consumer index
        if (cons_index == NITEMS - 1)
            cons_index = 0;
        else
            cons_index++;

        // release mutex lock and signal producer thread
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&bufferNotFull);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wait pattern wrong. It's:

```
    // acquire mutex lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // while buffer is empty, wait
    while (shared_count == 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&bufferNotEmpty,&mutex);
    } 

    // read key from shared buffer
    key = shared_buffer[cons_index];

    // echo key
    printf("consumer %d %c\n", id, key);

    // update shared count variable
    shared_count--;

    // update consumer index
    if (cons_index == NITEMS - 1)
        cons_index = 0;
    else
        cons_index++;

    // release mutex lock and signal producer thread
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&bufferNotFull);
```

Fix the other side the same way. You need a loop that waits until the condition is satisfied, and you want to hold the (possibly re-acquired) mutex while you mess with the shared state.

Notice I removed the first call to `pthread_cond_signal`. Whatever *made* the `shared_count` equal zero would already have woken the other thread. We didn't change anything yet, so there's nobody we need to tell anything to yet.

There is no point in notifying another thread if you haven't done anything that it needs to be notified about. You call `pthread_cond_signal` when you need to tell another thread that you changed some shared state that it might be waiting for.

Comment: I'm confused, the way my code is implemented now works just fine. Are you saying that it shouldn't work, or that the way you provided is just a better way to accomplish the goal?

Comment: @Remixt I'm saying that you got it to work in an overcomplicated way that reflects a lack of understanding of how to use the functions properly. It is also partially working by luck because it doesn't properly handle spurious wakeups and can unlock the mutex twice in a row.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be
>   owned by the calling thread
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait

`pthread_cond_wait()` will lock the mutex, so calling

```
pthread_cond_wait(&bufferNotEmpty,&mutex);
// mutex is already locked
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
// deadlock
```

will result in a deadlock

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!